# Intellisense issues in VS code

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am currently writing code on Windows and Mac.
As you can see in the picture I uploaded, Intellisense is working fine on Windows, but the methods are not showing up at all on Mac.
The settings on Windows and Mac are synchronized with each other.
How can I fix this on Mac?

Windows

[image: Windows]

Mac OS

[image: Mac OS]

Comment: The MacOS image shows word completion not "intellisense" have you got an extension installed on the Windows version that is not installed on the MacOS one?

Comment: VSCode has the [recommended extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_workspace-recommended-extensions) feature to install the same extentions for a given directory. Helps with analysing the problem you're having.

Comment: did you install `@types/node` on your mac yet?